# RLayers RLayerVector no height

Tags: reactjs, typescript, openlayers

I'm trying to use RLayers for a project, but I'm having a hard time with pretty simple task: "Add some 1 by 1 km squares to the map".
I don't know if it's the issue, but I can see when I inspect things that the RMap itself has the correct 100% height (also it works fine), but the RLayerVector has a height of 0 - which could explain why I can't see them:

```
<RMap width={"100%"} height={"100%"}
    initial={view}
    view={[view, setView]} 
    className="MapView">
    <ROSM />
    <div className="MapView_squares_overlay"> //this div might not be needed
        <RLayerVector zIndex={10}>
            <RStyle.RStyle>
                {/* styling for said squares */}
                <RStyle.RRegularShape points={4}>
                    <RStyle.RFill color="blue" />
                </RStyle.RRegularShape>
            </RStyle.RStyle>
            {zones.map((zone, index) => {
                const x1 = view.center[0]; //to assure that they're within the viewport
                const y1 = view.center[1];
                return <RFeature
                    key={index}
                    geometry={
                        new Polygon([
                            [
                                [x1, y1],
                                [x1, y1 + 1000],
                                [x1 + 1000, y1 + 1000],
                                [x1 + 1000, y1],
                                [x1, y1],
                            ],
                        ])
                    }
                    style={undefined}
                />;
            })}
        </RLayerVector>
    </div>
</RMap>
```

I got some styling to go with it, but I doubt that that is doing any difference right now:

```
.MapView{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.MapView_squares_overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a point style - it specifies a shape which means that it can be applied only to a point.

Transform your style to

```js
<RStyle.RStyle>
  <RStyle.RFill color='blue' />
</RStyle.RStyle>
```

and you will see them.

However they will tend to move around as you move and zoom since they depend on the view center.

Comment: I got around to that solution eventually - however, still no dice. Im still using the RLayerVector, with a high zIndex, and now a LineString between the coords. I can get the stroke working just fine, but that fill you're mentioning doesn't work. I got an extends property on it as well set to the the extends of the LineString.

Comment: A `Fill` will work only with a `Polygon`, a `LineString` has only a `Stroke`

Comment: So a LineString only supports stroke - while a Polygon only supports fill (i.e. layer them to get both)? Is there anywhere you can lookup what style properties each support?

Comment: Polygon supports both `Fill` and `Stroke`. These come from OpenLayers but I was not able to find any explicit documentation. All features that have lines support `Stroke`. `Polygon` and all icon-like shapes like `Circle` and `RegularShape` support `Fill`. Only `Point` supports icon-like shapes. They throw exceptions when nested improperly between them, but none throws an exception when applied to a feature because the feature type is not known in advance.

Comment: Using open layers for more custom graphics besides your standard location markers might be an edgecase depending on what it is usually used for. I found the ol geom documentation, but no mention of styling properties. Thx for taking the time btw. Greatly enjoy your library so far :)

Comment: You are welcome. *rlayers* has been mentioned before on SO, but you had the honor to ask the first question ever :-)